# how to use rxjs bindCallback

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to use bindCallback for mqtt-client connect-event (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#event-connect) and getting error. What am I doing wrong?

```
const client = mqtt.connect("...")
const clientOnObs = bindCallback(client.on)
clientOnObs('connect').subscribe(console.log)
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined
    at _addListener (events.js:203:19)
    at addListener (events.js:259:10)
    at Observable._subscribe (/Users/robert.rajakone/repos/2018_diprem/example-message-simulator/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/observable/bindCallback.ts:215:26)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Users/robert.rajakone/repos/2018_diprem/example-message-simulator/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:231:19)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Users/robert.rajakone/repos/2018_diprem/example-message-simulator/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Observable.ts:212:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/robert.rajakone/repos/2018_diprem/example-message-simulator/main.ts:30:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "mqtt": "^2.18.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
  }
}

node -v
v10.10.0

npm -v
6.5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use bindCallback on an object's function, you have to take care of the context. Operation bindCallback will invoke the function with apply and passing this as the current context. In order to fix it you can rewrite your code to:

```
const clientOnObs = bindCallback(client.on);
clientOnObs.call(client, 'connect').subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Another style:

```
const client = mqtt.connect("...")
const clientOnObs = bindCallback(client.on).bind(client)
clientOnObs('connect').subscribe(console.log)
```