# rxjs bindCallback Subscription on mqtt-client message-event only triggers once and does not trigger DataQueryResponse subscriber.next()

Tags: typescript, rxjs, grafana, grafana-plugin

I am currently trying to create a streaming DataSource plugin for Grafana. To do this, I have adapted the [code from the official instructions](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/build-a-streaming-data-source-plugin/) so that data from an MQTT Topic is passed to Grafana. Here is the official working demo code with a timed output of the `frame`:

### Code from the Grafana Guide

```
query(options: DataQueryRequest<MyQuery>): Observable<DataQueryResponse> {
  const streams = options.targets.map(target => {
    const query = defaults(target, defaultQuery);

    return new Observable<DataQueryResponse>(subscriber => {
      const frame = new CircularDataFrame({
        append: 'tail',
        capacity: 1000,
      });

      frame.refId = query.refId;
      frame.addField({ name: 'time', type: FieldType.time });
      frame.addField({ name: 'value', type: FieldType.number });

      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        frame.add({ time: Date.now(), value: Math.random() });

        subscriber.next({
          data: [frame],
          key: query.refId,
        });
      }, 100);

      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    });
  });

  return merge(...streams);
}
```

The connection to my Mosquitto broker and the submitting and receiving of the data works great. What is problematic is passing the received data to the Grafana dashboard through a subscriber that returns a `CircularDataFrame`.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55353838/5653638), I use the rxjs `bindCallback` function to watch the message eventhandler. In doing so, the console output within the message callback function is printed correctly for each incoming message. Whereas the console output in the subscription of the `clientOnObs` instance is only triggered on the first message and no more after that. However, it should be the case that the console output in the subscription is also triggered on each incoming message, so that I can expand the `CircularDataFrame` and then pass it to the Grafana Dashboard via `subscriber.next()`. I already tried swapping the order of `bindCallback()` and `this.mqttClient.on()`, but then no message was output in the `subscribe` part at all. Additionally I tried to put the `subscriber.next()` call directly into the `this.mqttClient.on('message')` callback, also without success.

**The goal is to have `subscriber.next()` fire on every incoming message to pass the new data to the dashboard. How do I need to modify my implementation of the `query` method to achieve this?**

### My adapted code

```
query(request: DataQueryRequest<MyQuery>): Observable<DataQueryResponse> {
    const streams = request.targets.map(target => {
      const query = defaults(target, defaultQuery);

      return new Observable<DataQueryResponse>(subscriber => {
        const frame = new CircularDataFrame({
          append: 'tail',
          capacity: 1000,
        });

        frame.refId = query.refId;
        frame.addField({ name: 'time', type: FieldType.time });
        frame.addField({ name: 'value', type: FieldType.number });

        const clientOnObs = bindCallback(this.mqttClient.on).bind(this.mqttClient);

        this.mqttClient.on('message', (topic: string, message: any) => {
          // this is printed correctly with every message
          console.log(topic, JSON.parse(message.toString()));
        });

        return () => {
          clientOnObs('message').subscribe((payload: any[]) => {
            // const topic: string = payload[0];
            const message = JSON.parse(payload[1].toString());
            
            // This is only printed on the first incoming message
            console.log(message);

            frame.add({ time: Math.floor(message.time) * 1000, value: message.temperature });
            
            // The frame is not passed on at all
            subscriber.next({
              data: [frame],
              key: query.refId,
            });
          });
        };
      });
    });

    return merge(...streams);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindCallback` is a function used to transform a callback-based function into an Obaservable which emits **once** and then completes. So this is probably the reason the subscription is triggered only for the first message.

If I look at your code, what I would try to do is the following

```
query(request: DataQueryRequest<MyQuery>): Observable<DataQueryResponse> {
    const streams = request.targets.map(target => {
      const query = defaults(target, defaultQuery);

      return new Observable<DataQueryResponse>(subscriber => {
        const frame = new CircularDataFrame({
          append: 'tail',
          capacity: 1000,
        });

        frame.refId = query.refId;
        frame.addField({ name: 'time', type: FieldType.time });
        frame.addField({ name: 'value', type: FieldType.number });

        this.mqttClient.on('message', (topic: string, message: any) => {
          // call next on the subscriber here
          const message = JSON.parse(payload[1].toString());
          frame.add({ time: Math.floor(message.time) * 1000, value: message.temperature });
          subscriber.next({
            data: [frame],
            key: query.refId,
          });
        });

        return () => {
          // place here any code that has to run to clean up when the Observable
          // completes. In the graphana official example, for instance, this is 
          // where the interval is cleared
        };
      });
    });

    return merge(...streams);
  }
```

Comment: Excellent, this solution properly displays the data in Grafana and is much easier than mine. Can you please explain in more detail what you mean by "to clean up when the Observable completes"?

Comment: Take the graphana example. They create an interval. If you do not clean that interval, it creates a memory leak. In your case maybe you need cleanup the `mqttClient`, but I am not sure since I am not familiar with Mosquitto.